# Convert [8]byte to a uint64

Tags: go

all. I'm encountering what seems to be a very strange problem. (It could be that it's far past when I should be asleep, and I'm overlooking something obvious.)

I have a `[]byte` with length 8 as a result of some hex decoding. I need to produce a `uint64` in order to use it. I have tried using [`binary.Uvarint()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Uvarint), from `encoding/binary` to do so, but it seems to only use the first byte in the array. Consider the following example.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    array := []byte{0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0xab, 0x01}
    num, _ := binary.Uvarint(array[0:8])
    fmt.Printf("%v, %x\n", array, num)
}
```

**[Here it is on play.golang.org.](http://play.golang.org/p/q0lCVvTfRD)**

When that is run, it displays the `num` as `0`, even though, in hex, it should be `000108000801ab01`. Furthermore, if one catches the second value from `binary.Uvarint()`, it is the number of bytes read from the buffer, which, to my knowledge, should be 8, even though it is actually 1.

Am I interpreting this wrong? If so, what should I be using instead?

Thanks, you all. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're decoding using a function whose use isn't the one you need :

> Varints are a method of encoding integers using one or more bytes;
>   numbers with smaller absolute value take a smaller number of bytes.
>   For a specification, see
>   http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html.

It's not the standard encoding but a very specific, variable byte number, encoding. That's why it stops at the first byte whose value is less than 0x080.

As pointed by Stephen, binary.BigEndian and binary.LittleEndian provide useful functions to decode directly :

```
type ByteOrder interface {
    Uint16([]byte) uint16
    Uint32([]byte) uint32
    Uint64([]byte) uint64
    PutUint16([]byte, uint16)
    PutUint32([]byte, uint32)
    PutUint64([]byte, uint64)
    String() string
}
```

So you may use

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    array := []byte{0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0xab, 0x01}
    num := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(array)
    fmt.Printf("%v, %x", array, num)
}
```

or (if you want to check errors instead of panicking, thanks jimt for pointing this problem with the direct solution) :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    array := []byte{0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0xab, 0x01}
    var num uint64
    err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(array[:]), binary.LittleEndian, &num)
    fmt.Printf("%v, %x", array, num)
}
```

Comment: You can avoid Read() and bytes.Buffer by just doing `num := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(array)`

Comment: @StephenWeinberg +1 I didn't knew that. I replaced my solution to use yours, which is cleaner.

Comment: It should be noted that these shortcut methods will panic if the input buffer is not large enough to hold the full requested data type. Using the `binary.Read` approach gives you an `error` return you can check.

Answer (score 2):

If don't care byte order, you can try this:

```
arr := [8]byte{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
num := *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&arr[0]))
```

http://play.golang.org/p/aM2r40ANQC

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the function for [Uvarint](http://weekly.golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/binary/varint.go?s=2073:2111#L50) you will see that it is not as straight a conversion as you expect.

To be honest, I haven't yet figured out what kind of byte format it expects (see edit).

But to write your own is close to trivial:

```
func Uvarint(buf []byte) (x uint64) {
    for i, b := range buf {
        x = x << 8 + uint64(b)
        if i == 7 {
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

**Edit**

The byte format is none I am familiar.
It is a variable width encoding where the highest bit of each byte is a flag.
If set to 0, that byte is the last in the sequence.
If set to 1, the encoding should continue with the next byte.

Only the lower 7 bits of each byte are used to build the uint64 value. The first byte will set the lowest 7 bits of the uint64, the following byte bit 8-15, etc.